# Need assistance with Proof for Nested Loops and Exponentials

Tags: algorithm, math, theory

Is it possible to express the growth of any nested loop as an exponential?  This is the discussion I am in with a few classmates. I tried to show, using the laws of exponents, that:

```
If n = the size of the outer loop
If k = the size of the inner loop

Then, if we use n as our base and the value of n is n^1:
Then, if n^x = k, the total = n^(1+x) for any n and k.
```

This should work for any base I think.  Also, the outer loop could technically be n raised to any power so long as you use the same base.

Edit:  code sample for clarification:

```
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){

  for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++){

   /// whatever

  }

}

Let us say that:
n = 10
k = 5

We would expect that the total would be 10 * 5 = 50
50 maximum loops

I am saying that:
10 = 10^1 -> outer loop
5 = 10^.69897 -> inner loop
10^1.69897 = 50
```

This should work for any base.

Comment: What is your definition of the *growth* and *size* of a loop? What does *total* represent?

Comment: By growth, we are talking about the rate of change with respect to the size of the inner loop.  The total represents the maximum number of times the innermost operation will run

Comment: So with *size* you mean *number of iterations*? Are *n* and *k* constants? If not, by which algorithm do they change?

Comment: Well, you can always write 10 * 5 = 10^1 * 10^log10(5) = 10^(1 + log10(5)) ...if this representation is useful to you, go ahead, use it.

Comment: I'm really trying to find out if this holds up or if it just happened to work here. I am still new with proofs.

Comment: Yes, any positive number n can be expressed as b^logb(n) and any product m * n as m^(1 + logm(n)), so if your complexity is a product of m * n, you can express it via aforementioned sum of exponents to base m.

Comment: Thank you @le_m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this has to do with loops, but generally suppose you have any two numbers, `n` and `k`, and you want to represent `n*k` at base `n`:

`n` would be `10` at base n
`k` would be `10^(log k)` (`log` here mean logarithm with base 10)

so `n*k = 10 * 10^(log k) = 10^(log k + 1)`
So yeah, the math holds up. But I'm not sure why you choose to look at it this way.

Comment: I kind of backed myself into a corner during a discussion and had to prove it.

Comment: Also, it never hurts to have one more way of doing something.